# Let $n$ be an integer $\geq 2$ and let $M_n(\Bbb R)$ denote....

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $n$ be an integer $\geq 2$ and let $M_n(\Bbb R)$ denote the vector space of $n \times n$ real matrices. Let $B \in M_n(\Bbb R)$be an orthogonal matrix and let $B^t$ denote the transpose of $B.$ Consider $W_B=\{B^tAB:A \in M_n(\Bbb R)\}.$ Then I have to show that

> 1. $W_B$ is a subspace of $M_n(\Bbb R)$ and dim $W_B$=rank $(B)$rank $(B^t)$ and
> 2. $W_B=M_n(\Bbb R).$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Who gave you these steps? It is obvious that $W_B=M_n(\mathbb{R})$, as $\phi:A\longmapsto B^TAB$ is an isomorphism with inverse $A\longmapsto BAB^T$. Or if you prefer, $\phi$ is clearly injective, hence onto by the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @julien I don't see a nice way to prove 1 without proving 2 do you see one ? :D

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Actually, 1 would be interesting for $B$ arbitrary. Then write $B=PJ_rQ$ with $P,Q$ invertible and $J_r$ the diagonal matrix $\{1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots,0\}$ with $r=\mbox{rank} B$ ones. Then $W_B=W_{J_r}$ is easily seen to be isomorphic to $M_r$ by blocks, hence has dimension $r^2$.

Comment: I am surprised you raise a bounty on this. $W_B=\phi(M_n(\mathbb{R}))$ where $\phi$ is the morphism I defined above. In particular, $W_B$ contains $\phi(BAB^t)=A$ for every $A$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. So $W_B$ contains $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Thus $W_B=M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. $W_B$ is the image of a certain linear map--it may be easier to compute the kernel of this map
2. Use 1. to show that $\dim W_B=\dim \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ using the fact that both $B$ and $B^t$ are invertible.